# Why does this xml schema become invalid for a .NET DataSet when adding the maxOccurs indicator?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

When passing the xml below to DataSet.ReadXml function in a C# program (using .NETFramework v4.8), the function throws an exception indicating that the declaration of `foo` is duplicated ("Duplicated declaration 'foo'").

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="container" type="containerType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="containerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="A" type="AType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="B" type="BType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="BType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Removing the maxOccurs indicators from foo somehow removes the error. i.e. this xml is accepted by the function

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="container" type="containerType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="containerType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="A" type="AType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="B" type="BType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="BType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Why is the previous version invalid if this one is valid ?

I tried reading the Microsoft's documentation for the function, but I didn't find anything that seemed relevant.

I also tried changing the value of maxOccurs. The xml was accepted only when using the default value of 1.

Changing the name of one of the `foo` would remove the error and keep the maxOccurs, of course, but this would not answer the question of *why* there is an error. Also, I would be interested in knowing if there is a different workaround.

Edit:
The C# validation code as requested :

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
static class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
      if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         var ds = new DataSet();
         try
         {
            //Throws if given a file containing the first schema example
            ds.ReadXml(ofd.FileName);
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: While asking an XSD question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and complete XSD that tried to implement it.
(3) XSD processor and its conformance with the XSD standards: 1.0, or 1.1.
(4) c# validation code.

Comment: If the `maxOccurs` is unbounded then how would the parser know if a `foo` is from `AType` or `BType`?

Comment: What is the actual text of the error message you get? Don't truncate or re-word it, just copy and paste it verbatim.

Comment: @Charlieface Could it not use the enclosing `A` or `B`? Even without the maxOccurs, `<container><foo/></container>`  is not a valid input for the schema (but `<container><A><foo/></A></container>` is).

Comment: Why would this be a valid schema for a `DataSet`? It has some very specific requirements for schemas, one of them seems to be that each column can only be defined once, so makes no sense for a type to have multiple of the same node. What exactly are you trying to do with this XSD that you need it in a `DataSet`?

Comment: @mamift I added the full message to the description : "Duplicated declaration 'foo'". I hope it helps.

Comment: @Charlieface I am not familiar at all with DataSet (or C# for that matter) so this might be it. If you can afford the time, I would greatly appreciate a full answer with excerpts from Microsoft's documentation and an explanation on why this schema could be valid on its own, but not in the context of a DataSet.
For reference, I don't know that I need a DataSet, but if I want to not use it, I need to explain to a colleague why they need to change their code and preferably how.

Comment: DataSet is for an ADO.Net set of tables with relationships. For generic XSD validation, use `XmlReader` and/or Linq2XML https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/validate-xsd

Comment: Please edit your question, and provide (1) Well-formed input XML.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Given that the problem is fully reproducible with what is already given and that I don't have xml input to provide, I will not add any.

Answer (score 0):

The schema document you supplied is a valid XSD schema, and Saxon accepts it as valid. The problem seems to be a limitation in Microsoft's DataSet class. I see the following note in the documentation:

> If the schema for your DataSet contains elements of the same name, but
> different type, in the same namespace, an exception is thrown when you
> attempt to read the schema into the DataSet with ReadXml by specifying
> XmlReadMode.ReadSchema. This exception does not occur if you are using
> .NET Framework version 1.0.

I've no idea how you work around this: it rather depends on what you are trying to achieve in your project and why you have chosen this particular technology to achieve it.

Comment: while the problem is probably indeed that this schema is inappropriate for a DataSet, I am not sure that the documentation quote is applicable to this case. The elements signaled as duplicates by the exception message share both the same name **and** the same type.